# Spring Security (Java Configuration) problems

Tags: java, security, spring-security, spring-4, userdetailsservice

***Hello everybody,***

I have a task where I have to create 3 pages: 
**/login**- where we have email and password inputs, 
**/result** - where we have to tell user does he authificated or not, and in case of successful we can show 3rd page - 
**/dataEntry**  where we can saveOrUpdate user's info in DataBase.

**The difference of typical project is users email and passwords are in USERS.XML not in DataBase(DB)**

I've parsed it by **sax** and **dom**.

Parser returns **HashMap** where '**key**' is '**email**'and '**value**' is '**password**'.

**Than I did default domains:**

1) **Login.class** - is the main class to auth and to work only with users.xml.
It has next fields: email , password.

2) **User.class** - to work with DB (save,update,load user's info). It has next fields: id, email, firstName, secondName, gender.

Next I did **dao** and **service** layers of this domains.
On the bottom of my ask I will give a link for bitbucket but please read my question all.

I configure project by Java , so I did **Hibernate configuration** (it works correct), **Web configuration** (seems like it works correctly too) and **Security Configuration** (at this moment I want to start crying).

**My Security Configuration:**

SecurityWebApplicationInitializer

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
}
```

SecurityConfiguration

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

/**
 * Holds userDetailsService
 */
@Autowired
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

/**
 * Gets BCryptPasswordEncoder object.
 *
 * @return BCryptPasswordEncoder object.
 */
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

/**
 * Gets DaoAuthenticationProvider with its parameters
 *
 * @return authenticationProvider
 */
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authenticationProvider;
}

/**
 * Sets GlobalSecurity parameters.
 *
 * @param auth - AuthenticationManagerBuilder object.
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

/**
 * Sets Encoding parameters to work with russian locale, filters to get access to any page.
 * /index is login and logout page by default - everybody can open this page.
 * /result is page with results of login - everybody can open this page.
 * /dataEntry is page to save/update/load user's info - only registered user can open this page.
 *
 * @param http - {@link HttpSecurity} object
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //To work with UTF-8 and RU locale
    CharacterEncodingFilter f = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    f.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    f.setForceEncoding(true);

    http
            .addFilterBefore(f, CsrfFilter.class)
            .formLogin().loginPage("/index").defaultSuccessUrl("/result")
            .usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/index").invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and().httpBasic().realmName("ArtezioWebApp")
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/index", "/result/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/result/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER","ROLE_ANONYMOUS")
            .antMatchers("/dataEntry/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
            .and().csrf()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/result?error");
}
```

CustomUserDetailsService

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {

/**
 * Holds logger.
 */
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);

/**
 * Holds {@link LoginService} object
 */
@Autowired
@Qualifier("loginService")
private LoginService loginService;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("login")
Login login;

/**
 * Gets UserDetailsService object with parameters - email, password, authorities.
 *
 * @param email - by default has alias 'userName'
 * @return UserDetailsService object with email,password and authorities.
 * @throws UsernameNotFoundException if user was not found in *.xml file.
 */
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    //All users emails and passwords
    HashMap<String, String> h = loginService.getUsers();
    logger.info("Searching user with email '{}'...", email);

    if (loginService.isValidEmail(email)) {
        logger.info("User with email '{}' was found.", email);

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        //Saves data in Login object
        login.setPassword(h.get(email));
        login.setEmail(email);
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(login.getEmail(),
                login.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, authorities);
    }
    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with email '" + email + "' not found.");
}
```

When I debugged project I noticed that @Overloaded method loadByUsername(String email) is never invoked.

SecurityContext returns me anonymusUser even I entered correct email and password.
So I cant get access to /dataEntry page.

LINK TO BITBUCKET: [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/fragaLY/artezio-web-app/)

Anybody please help me.
Thank you much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add login-processing-url as "/j_spring_security_check" to work and add action on your login form as "j_spring_security_check".
Read more here : [Spring migration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-form-login)